# How to retrieve value from dynamic button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a dynamic button inside c# code and I have assigned some value in `button.text` but the problem is that on `buttn_Click` event I want to show details related to that value. So any idea how to do this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        lnk1 = new Button();


        VW obj1 = list[i];


        lnk1.Text = "    "+obj1.ticketNo+":      "+obj1.subject+":       "+obj1.qu;
        lnk1.Click += new EventHandler(lnk1_Click);
    }
}
```

I want to show above mentioned obj1.ticketno in next page like ticket No: some value is selected

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the reference to the button using the `sender` parameter of the event handler and cast the value to the Button type.

Answer (score 0):

In lnk1_Click event handler you can get the link by type casting the sender to Button type and get the link text. Using that you can retrieve ticket number for which click has been done.

Something like this:

```
void lnk1_Click(object sender)
{
    Button clickedLinkButton = sender as Button;
    String buttonText = clickedLinkButton .Text;
    String clickedTicketNumber = 
                                  buttonText
                                  .SubString(0, buttonText.IndexOf(':'))
                                  .Trim();"    
}
```

Comment: Hi Maheep, in lnk1_Click(object sender) i am creating two more dynamic button and i am creating event like button.Click+= new EventHandler(button_Click); same as above.and also crearted event but it is not at all triggering. void button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e){Response.redirect("some url");} but it is not trigerring and if i click data created by parent dynamic button event also disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code segment

```
 protected void lnk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Button bt = sender as Button;
        bt.Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use GridView or Repeater and in Iteme Template you can put button. and bind perticular grid or repeater.

    <asp:repeater runat="server" id="rpt">

    </ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="serevr" ID="lbtnLInkButton"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Edit" OnClick="lbtnLInkButton_Click">"+<%#Eval("ticketNo")%>  <%#Eval("subject")%>  <%#Eval("qu")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:repeater>


    Bind This Repeater to Datatable or make Dummy DataTable and bind it.


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ticketNo");
            dt.Columns.Add("Subject");
            dt.Columns.Add("qu");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {

      dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ticket Number Value", "Subject Value", "qu Value"});

    }

    rpt.DataSource = dt;
    rpt.DAtabind();

You can get button event like this 

    protected void lbtnLInkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);

        }



***Note : I have writtern the code extempore and not rested it on Visual Studio so there  May be Some Spelling Mistakes.**
```

Comment: is there any other way to do .

Comment: is your button in usercontrol or you have created at runtime in your aspx page?